# How to specify different logfile with each log entry

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have a following script which works as logging module for other scripts in my application:

**logger.js**

```
winston = require('winston');

var fileLog =  new (winston.Logger)({
    transports:[
        new (winston.transports.File)({filename: filename.log})
    ]
});

module.exports.fileLog = fileLog;
```

I use this logging module in scripts the following way:

**script.js**

```
var logger = require('./logger');
logger.fileLog.log('info','Chill winston');
```

Right now all the log entries are saved to *filename.log*, but I would like to be able to specify a different logfile each time I log an entry from **script.js**

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue by a custom function in my logging module.

**logger.js**

```
winston = require('winston');

function fileLogF(filename,level,msg) {
    if(typeof fileLog == 'undefined' || (fileLog.transports.file.filename)!= filename){
        fileLog =  new (winston.Logger)({
            transports:[
                new (winston.transports.File)({filename: filename,json:false }),
            ],
        })
    }
    fileLog.log(level,msg);
}
```

Now I can specify a logfile when making a log entry:

**script.js**

```
var logger = require('./logger');
logger.fileLog('filename.log','info','Chill winston');
```